# Var keyword in Java

Tags: java, var

With Java 10 or +, we can use `var` keyword for declaration. At initialization, a type is going to be inferred by the compiler.

What happens when the class I instantiate and assign to the variable declared with `var`, is the implementation of the interface?  Which type is it going to be inferred, Interface or the implementation?

Comment: It'll be the actual type, i. e. the implementation. (A class can implement multiple interfaces.)

Comment: See G5 here: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html

Comment: The recommendation of "programming to the interface" is somewhat relaxed for local variables.

Comment: @user7655213 not really, please check my sample code

Answer (score 38):

My 2 cents to correct the question and answers:

1. The `var` is **NOT a Java keyword**. It's a **reserved type name**. It seems not a big difference but in fact, it IS:

   ```
   var var = 0;
   ```

   Here `var` is a variable name too, so the `var` can be used as a type name, but there is no restriction like for regular keyword (i.e. we can have a variable named `var` too).
2. The actual type of the variable IS decided by the Java compiler on the line where the variable is declared, at compile-time, but the type is NOT actually the exact implementation you use on the right side of the expression. See this code:

   ```
   var i = true ? Integer.valueOf(1) : "ABC";
   ```

   The Java compiler needs to pick a type for variable `i` which will satisfy both branches. It could be a) `Object`, b) `Serializable`, c) `Comparable`, or combination, or all three. We don't care and don't know.

Comment: @trashgod for reference, the `ContextualKeyword` was added only in Java 17 JLS, while my answer (and question too) dated before Java 17 was released.

Answer (score 25):

### Answer to your question:

> What happens when the class I instantiate and assign to the variable declared with var, is the implementation of the interface? which type is it going to be inferred, Interface or the implementation?

Inferred type of the variable will be exactly *the class*, reference to the instance of which you're assigning to the variable declared with `var`.

Regarding "interface" point: if it (class of the object, reference to which you assign to variable declared with "var") is an implementation of some interface, what do you think will happen if that class implements two or more interfaces? how, do you think, Java should decide on which super-type (i.e. interface) to infer for the variable? this is impossible even by basing our judgement purely on a logic (without any relation to Java) - there will be no "source of truth", by which, Java would be able to decide on this.

---

### Motivation for *var* keyword:

Remember, that the only stated purpose of using `var`, according to the language designers (since JDK 10+), has been the point to beautify the code and make it more readable (which, I personally think, is a non-sense as having "var" in Java, is worse than having explicit types, and in many ways so).

For example, this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/"); 
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

is (according to official [JEP 286](https://openjdk.org/jeps/286) document) less clear to read than:

```
var url = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/"); 
var conn = url.openConnection(); 
var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

---

### Implementation details:

`var` was introduced with the purpose of serve the *cleaner/better readability* and NOT to amend the Type System of the Java language. That's why, you can't use it in the class level (for static or instance) fields, because fields might be used with polymorphism (might receive different implementation types, might be injected by IoC, or etc.) and at the bytecode, it's not possible to dynamically change the field type for each different case.

---

## Update:

### Why I think "var" is bad and why I try to avoid it?

Well, for several reasons:

1. code gets actually *harder* to read, and not only in a sense of merely reading it, but also in a sense, that you may have hard times when trying to understand what is the *actual* type you are getting the reference to. Imagine if the actual object creation expression is some long builder pattern code.. or factory pattern call.. or etc. you basically have to go and open/decompile the source and see what you get. So, it's harder to read and harder to understand;
2. this will often lead (especially a bit less experienced in Java) engineers to confusion whether typing becomes dynamic or keeps static;
3. polymorphic calls are not supported and polymorphism, in general, is not possible, because compiler cannot infer different types with the same code;
4. code actually gets inconsistent, as you'll be having explicit types for fields and "var"s for local variables. This will also (but not only) confuse newcomers to Java;
5. maybe not that important.. but this **can** be important as well: "var" will also break backwards compatibility, as you won't be able to downgrade to the Java version below 10.

Comment: To me var makes the code harder to read as it hides the type of a variable.  When I am reading code I like to see the variable types clearly and explicitly declared regardless if the variable is local or not.

Comment: @RubensGomes I agree to some extent. I, myself, also don't use it almost at all.

Comment: Having type declaration is clear to read. How can obscuring type information make anything clearer? It does not. var keyword saves some some typing at the cost of obscuring information. Most IDEs will autocomplete this. You are not writing by hand.

Comment: I agree . var should be removed from Java. The people who introduced also should be transferred to JavaScript

Comment: 100% agree with you.  I see no way in which the use of `var` is desirable.  As someone trying to nurture a culture of readable code, I find it really annoying.  What's wrong with typing a few extra characters to specify the type (and getting immediate feedback if you made a bad assumption?) If I don't know the compile-time type of a Java variable when I declare it, well, then I shouldn't be coding.  I see nothing good and plenty bad about this.

Comment: I agree 100% ! I can not believe it was introduced in Java for such weak reasons...

Comment: To be honest, I totally disagree. I do absolutely prefer `for (var entry:map.entrySet())` over `for (Map.Entry<Integer,SortedSet<String>> entry:map.entrySet())`. If I really cannot deduce the type from context, I still can use IDE's help by hovering over the `var` keyword to see the actual type.

Comment: Sonarqube flags not using "var" as a code smell.  Here where I work, we're going to take that rule out of sonarqube since, like most of you, we find that using "var" only obfuscates the variable type, especially when the type is inferred from a method return value.  
Personally, this seems to have been introduced by people that were used to reading Javascript and didn't want to acclimate to Java's strong-typed syntax.  Even my OCD doesn't mind seeing the overt type declarations.

Comment: @astrien I know several other teams that have disabled that sq rule. :)

Answer (score 9):

The other answers so far don't stress one important point, the distinction between compile-time deducible type and run-time instance class.

Suppose we have

```
var data = Collections.singleton("test");
```

Then, the compiler can see that `Collections.singleton("test")` is declared to return `Set<String>`. So `data` effectively gets declared as `Set<String>` (not e.g. `Collection<String>` nor `Object` nor `Collections.SingletonSet`). `Set<String>` is the most specific info the compiler can find out.

When running, the instance referenced in `data` will be of some implementation class (e.g. `Collections.SingletonSet`), decided upon by the `Collections.singleton()` method, meaning that `data.getClass()` will not return the `Set` class, but something different that implements the `Set` interface, i.e. `Collections.SingletonSet`.

So we have to consider three types:

1. The run-time class of the instance that gets assigned to the variable (e.g. a `Collections.SingletonSet`). This will of course always be compatible with (2) and (3), and cannot be known at compile-time.
2. The compile-time type of the expression that you assign to the variable (e.g. `Set<String>`).
3. The declared type of the variable. Classically, you'd find that explicitly left of the variable name, and when using the `var` keyword, the compiler treats it as if declared with the type from (2) (i.e. `Set<String>`).

Answer (score 6):

The 'official' Local Variable Type Inference style guide (https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) raises this concern, but says:

> "It must be reiterated here that var can only be used for local
> variables. It cannot be used to infer field types, method parameter
> types, and method return types. The principle of "programming to the
> interface" is still as important as ever in those contexts."

and

> "If, as recommended in guideline G2, the scope of the local variable
> is small, the risks from "leakage" of the concrete implementation that
> can impact the subsequent code are limited."

Answer (score 0):

The type will be exactly the same of the value the variable gets assigned to.

In case you are more concerned with interface over implementation idea: you can create function which returns interface type but creates a specific implementation instance inside.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph: or simply declare the variable with the interface type instead of using the `var` keyword.