# How to optimise this filtering of list in Java

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have the following code:

```java
private List<String> validate(StartValue start, List<String> colors, Entity entity) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(colors)) {
        return colors.stream()
                     .filter(color -> ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues(start, color.getRGBValue()).isEmpty() ||
                                      (!ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues(start, color.getRGBValue()).isEmpty() &&
                                       ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues(start, color.getRGBValue()).contains(entity.getColor())))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return colors;
}
```

Here `ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues` is getting called thrice for each value in the list. Is there a way to optimize the filter so that we can save the value of the call?

Comment: `colors` is `List<String>` so `colors.stream()` will return `Stream<String>` which means that `color`, in `.filter(color -> ` is a string and there is no `getRGBValue()` method in class `String` so how does your code even compile?

Answer (score 2):

If you would have not represented the code as a lambda expression, but as a block statement you would have been able to simplify it further.

```
.filter(color -> {
    List<String> colourFulValues = ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues(start,
                    color.getRGBValue());
    return colourFulValues.isEmpty() || colourFulValues.contains(entity.getColor())
}
```

Of course, you could abstract the block as a `Predicate` of its own depending on its usage. The type of the Predicate would be the type you have chosen to represent the color. Currently, in your question, for example, if it's a `java.lang.String`, where is the method `color.getRGBValue()` associated from?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```java
private List<String> validate(StartValue start, List<String> colors, Entity entity) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(colors)) {
        return colors.stream()
                     .filter(this::filter)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return colors;
}

private boolean filter(String color) {
    var rgbVal = color.getRGBValue();
    var cv = ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues(start, rgbVal);
    boolean empty = cv.isEmpty();
    return empty || (!empty && cv.contains(entity.getColor()));
}
```

Note that I use [var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63073153/var-keyword-in-java) since it is not clear to me what `color.getRGBValue()` returns and also what `ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues()` returns.

Comment: The `!empty &&` is redundant. Besides that, `getRGBValue()` doesn’t return anything because `String` does not have such a method at all…

Answer (score 0):

- Guessing that `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` considers null elements non-existing.
- For the filter condition evaluating `ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues(start, color.getRGBValue()))` only once requires mapping to it. But one needs to conserve the color too, to collect it in a list. So I introduced a `record ColorWithValues`. The `record` class is intended for such kind of uses.
- `||` is a short-circuit operator and does not need a negation of its first argument.

So:

```
private List<String> validate(StartValue start, List<String> colors, Entity entity) {
    record ColorWithValues(String color, Set<String> values) {}
    return colors.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(c ->
                     new ColorWithValues(c,
                         ValidationUtil.getColorfulValues(start, c.getRGBValue())))
                .filter(cv -> cv.values.isEmpty() ||
                              cv.values.contains(entity.getColor()))
                .map(cv -> cv.color)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```